# MySQL JOIN + WHERE + GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Here DB Structure:

```
turns DB Table
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| turnNumber| userId      | locationId | status     | itemsPurchased |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| 32        | 1           | 1          | 1          | 20             |
| 33        | 2           | 1          | 0          | 0              |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+

locations DB Table
+-----------+---------+---------+
| id        | Address | ZIPCode | 
+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1         | ...     | 12345   | 
| 2         | ...     | 67890   | 
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Im trying to get every location data (Address, ZIPCode...) + the amount of turns pending (with status 0) per location + the sum of items purchased per location (for all turns even if their state is 1)

Here my Query:

```
SELECT 
    l.*, 
    COUNT(t.id) AS turns,
    SUM(IF(t.itemsPurchased > 0, t.itemsPurchased, 0)) AS items
FROM turns t RIGHT OUTER JOIN locations l
ON t.locationId = l.id          
WHERE t.status = 0 AND
l.ZIPCode = XXXX 
GROUP BY l.id
```

The thing is when i put the t.status condition it doesnt get the location data when theres no turn with status 0 in turns table, also even if it would, i guess the count for items purchased would take in count only turns with status 0 and not all turns.

Im wondering if theres a way to get all data within the same query, please Help!

**Edit:**

The expected output is as following:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| id        | Address     | ZIPCode    | turns      | itemsPurchased |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| 1         | ...         | 12345      | 1          | 20             |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Show us the expected output.

Comment: @RobertHarvey done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition "`t.status = 0`" in the `WHERE` clause negates the "outerness" of the join; the same result we'd get with an INNER JOIN.

With the outer join, any rows in `locations` that don't have a matching row in `turns` will be returned with NULL values for the all of the `t.` columns. The unmatched rows from `locations` are going to get excluded by the condition in the WHERE clause.

---

Consider relocating that condition from the `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause of the outer join.

Or consider relocating that condition into an aggregate expression.

As an example:

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.zipcode
     , SUM(IF(t.status = 0, 1, 0)) AS turns
     , SUM(IF(t.status = 0 AND t.itemspurchased > 0, t.itemspurchased, 0)) AS items
 FROM locations l

 LEFT 
 JOIN turns t
   ON t.locationid = l.id
  AND t.status     = 0 

WHERE l.zipcode = XXXX 
GROUP
   BY l.id
    , l.zipcode
```

Comment: "The condition "t.status = 0" in the WHERE clause negates the "outerness" of the join; the same result we'd get with an INNER JOIN." True and it can be a very easy mistake to make.. i made a habit out of it to do the filtering always in the ON clause which does not uses `IS NULL` column checks with LEFT|RIGHT JOIN then you can never go wrong. So i would also placed `l.zipcode = XXXX ` in the ON clause here.

Comment: thanks i just had to remove completely the t.status = 0 condition and using your suggestion of adding turns only when they are with status 0 (SUM(IF(t.status = 0, 1, 0)) AS turns) i got everything i need!

Answer (score 0):

Using a LEFT JOIN and putting the criteria on different places.

To avoid that by using a criteria in the WHERE clause for the LEFT JOIN'd table, that it would give it the effect on as it were an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
loc.ZIPCode,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE turns.status WHEN 0 THEN turns.id END) AS turns,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN turns.status = 1 AND turns.itemsPurchased > 0 
    THEN turns.itemsPurchased 
    ELSE 0 
    END) AS items
FROM locations loc
LEFT JOIN turns ON turns.locationId = loc.id
WHERE loc.ZIPCode = 12345
GROUP BY loc.id, loc.ZIPCode
```